why inline_message_id is None?
Why < inline_message_id > value in the <on_chosen_inline_result> handler is None ??
it should be message id
my on_inline_query handler
@app.on_inline_query(filters.regex(p))
async def handler1(c,q):
    text1 = "link for user{}"
    user = q.from_user.id
    user = await app.get_users(sender)
    await q.answer(
                results=[
                    InlineQueryResultArticle(
                        title=text1,
                        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(f"message content "),
                        url="https://t.me/mybot",
                        description=text1.format(user),
                        thumb_url="",
                        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                            [
                                [
                                    InlineKeyboardButton(
                                        "donwload it",
                                        callback_data='getit',
                                    )
                                ]
                            ]
                        ),
                    )
                ],
    )

handler for test and print inline_message_id
@app.on_chosen_inline_result()
async def handler323(c,q):
    message_id = q.inline_message_id
    time = dt.datetime.now().isoformat(sep=" ", timespec="seconds")
    print(message_id) # why is None ???? 

